# If a logic first-order one if it allows variables to range over functions?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, higher-order-logic

Perhaps a stupid question but important to me:

I know that a second-order logic allows predicates as variables, such as:
$$\forall P. P(x) \to P(y).$$

But how about functions? For example,
$$f(x) + 1 > 2$$
is a first-order logical formula or a second-order one? And how to evaluate the free variables ($f$ and $x$?) of this formula so that it is true? (I know how to define an evaluation for $x$, like $E(x) = 2$. But how $E(f) = ?$. And in this formula, it seems wrong to evaluate both $f$ and $x$?)

At last, perhaps a more general problem I wish to solve:

**Is that possible, or what is a correct way to define the concept of "validation" for all logics?**

In other words, is it correct to say "a logical formula is valid if it is true under all evaluations of its free variables" for all kinds of logics?

Comment: No, for FOL only individual variables are quantified.

Comment: Second-order logics are allowed functions. You can implement them as a special case of binary predicate, or just talk about functions directly.